# What's a good way to detect a method is called with different parameters?

Tags: typescript

Let us say we have a method we would like it to return the same last result, if none of its parameters have changed from the last invocation.
How should we go about checking its parameters have not changed?
Cache the parameters in an object? array? for later check.

```
Compute( p1:boolean, p2:number, p3:number) {
 // if any of p1 or p2 or p3 have changed from last invocation 
 // then redo computation
 // else return last result. 
}
```

In the past when dealing with a single parameter I have used a field like p1_last and compare to it on entry.
something like this

```
  if (p1 == this.p1_last) {
    return this.result
  }
  else {
    this.p1_last = p1 // save p1 for next invocation.
    result = ....some algo....
    return this.result
  }
```

Your thoughts and suggested appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a general function that memorizes the inputs for a function passed.

```js
function memorize<F extends (...args: any) => any>(func: F): F {
  const cache = new Map()
  
  return function (this: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    // update the key calculation according to type of args
    const argsKey = args.toString()
    const cacheValue = cache.get(argsKey)
    
    if (cacheValue) console.log('cache working')
    if (cacheValue) return cacheValue
    
    const result = func.apply(this, args)
    cache.set(argsKey, result)
    
    return result
  } as F
}

let compute = function (p1: boolean, p2: number, p3: number) {
  // sample computation
  if (p1) return p2 * p3
  return p2 + p3
}

compute = memorize(compute)

let x = compute(true, 1, 2)
console.log(x)
x = compute(true, 1, 2) // cached
console.log(x)
x = compute(false, 1, 2)
console.log(x)
x = compute(false, 1, 2) // cached
console.log(x)
x = compute(false, 3, 2)
console.log(x)
x = compute(false, 3, 2) // cached
console.log(x)
x = compute(true, 1, 2) // cached
console.log(x)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKbLgJxgL1QHgDFFUAPKVMAEwGdEAKAOmYENMBzGgLkRbAE8AlIgC8APl4Cx9UJB6FB8xAG8AUIkQQENKJpYQAFqlGIwqAO6IAsiwAO9QesRPMqKCExJZ0eEnpQDGG5EcABrMDhzMAAaRGZGNk4eMIiogG0AXUUQsHDIpDUNDQB6YpDbKhYKRADjUNR+PQAbCBAmqt9eCC1MKhgwdhq4Gv5bYzhgXg4aJw0tMB0pzgBpBpNEmkYoOABlKGwBh1nNbV0IfSMANRYmkGMRPUNURnY3eg3VoWPjmEn6c6e11uqGE8xocCazyacHY9AA5ACjIhzFhQv12HDHEVEL8GIjUEC7sJXO5PI8rjc7t9sWDdK4aG1dA9vAlbLYmvx-IEaLENliivjGDQ3h8GrF6Yz+RpjiSPEgJU0oE4AL68OiEVTK1SqSFnODIWwgarM8A+BAMWwARh4ACM4BDUHxYrYAEw8MAgZA21CYZ0AZndnu9mGEhUQpUQNBYBshJwNRo6CCcuPoVuJbjliFdiAAVFm-S4M2TswBqfOa7VaePGlDoLC4VD-fWGiiOHVuRCkExVluN-Z3WKW2Iuxxgh2MaGw0iOLsPHtGvuYAeIIeIEfhsr4qiqMeQicw+jT1SzuO9mQ3YWD4ej7TjyeHmfd5sL89NS8r68b8mobe7qEHo8T3nChX3fP1rx3W893vQCn2rRtgAvVBYnAtdhAjLdIIWO8AMfOdnxA-tkI-NCv0wv99ynQQgA)

Comment: Wow! interesting solution, you probably have antennas on top of your head :)
I have to spend an hour understand all that syntax of memorize you used :)  but I am kind of programmer who uses things in black boxes.  It's probably not applicable to large data, perhaps overkill in my situation. I like how after compute = memorize(compute)  you kind of redefined compute and the usage is natural.
I will accept it as solution/answer as I may use it in the future.  Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Meryan Welcome! You might need to change `const str = args.toString()` as per your use case and depending on the type of parameters `func` can take. Updated answer a bit!

Answer (score 3):

If the number of parameters is fixed, it should be trivial to check against an array:

```
let lastParams: [boolean, number, number];
let lastResult; // type this properly...
function Compute( p1:boolean, p2:number, p3:number) {
  if (
    lastParams &&
    lastParams[0] === p1 &&
    lastParams[1] === p2 &&
    lastParams[2] === p3
  ) {
    return lastResult;
  }
  lastResult = /* some computation */
  lastParams = [p1, p2, p3];
  return lastResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
private ComputeLastParams = {}
private ResultLast 
Compute( p1:boolean, p2:number, p3:number) {
  if ( ObjectEqual ( {p1, p2, p3}, this.ComputeLastParams )
  ) {
    return this.ResultLast 
  }
  //
  this.ResultLast = /* some computation */
  this.ComputeLastParams = {p1, p2, p3}
  return this.ResultLast 
}
```

```
static ObjectEqual(object1, object2) {
        const keys1 = Object.keys(object1);
        const keys2 = Object.keys(object2);

        if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (let key of keys1) {
            if (object1[key] !== object2[key]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```